# Get a list of YouTube Music library uploads with ytmusicapi

Tags: python, youtube

I need to get a list of all albums of my YouTube Music uploads library with **[ytmusicapi](https://github.com/sigma67/ytmusicapi)** and I never work with Python before. I created the `headers_auth.json` and a `test.py` file with the following code from the example:

```
from ytmusicapi import YTMusic

ytmusic = YTMusic('headers_auth.json')
playlistId = ytmusic.create_playlist("test", "test description")
search_results = ytmusic.search("Oasis Wonderwall")
ytmusic.add_playlist_items(playlistId, [search_results[0]['videoId']])
```

I ran from the Ubuntu terminal:  `python /home/do/Desktop/ytmusicapi/ytmusicapi-master/test.py`

**Result error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/do/Desktop/ytmusicapi/ytmusicapi-master/test.py", line 1, in
>
> from ytmusicapi import YTMusic   File "/home/do/Desktop/ytmusicapi/ytmusicapi-master/ytmusicapi/**init**.py",
> line 2, in 
> from ytmusicapi.ytmusic import YTMusic   File "/home/do/Desktop/ytmusicapi/ytmusicapi-master/ytmusicapi/ytmusic.py",
> line 28
> auth: str = None,
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How to fix that?

Comment: Which python version are you running? check this by running `python --version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using a different version of Python.
The library you are using [requires Python>=3.5](https://github.com/sigma67/ytmusicapi#requirements) wheraas you seem to be using Python2.

If you are curious this code

```
def f(x:int):
    return
```

is valid in Python3.5+ versions but not in Python2.

You will have to either switch to Python3 to use that library or else you can clone the [repo](https://github.com/sigma67/ytmusicapi) and convert the whole repo to Python2 using something like [this](https://pypi.org/project/3to2/)(though there might be other ways too).

I'd recommend you simply switch to Python3.5 or higher.